# Blazor debugging - IIS doesn't update wwwroot files

Tags: visual-studio, iis, blazor

I'm developping a Blazor application client-side with Visual Studio. And when I run the app in debug, my css and js files are not updated.

I tried to clear browser cache, clean and rebuild the solution, quit IIS, reboot... and my files still remain in the old version.

I even renamed a js file, but when my browser download the app, he still download the old js file and not the new one.

How can I force the update when I make some changes in my css or js files ?

Comment: Do you start Blazor project or the project with ASP.NET Core Web App which servers your Blazor client?

Comment: I start the ASP.NET Core Web App server project

Comment: Could you check whether problem exists, if you start the client directly?

Comment: It works, the css is well updated, but I got an error at the startup :

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not load settings from '_configuration/BlazorWebApp.Client

Comment: But when I set back the server as startup project, it was looking for the appsetting.json in the client folder. I had to delete the bin and obj folders

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I could reproduce the issue, just disable caching:

[image]

Comment: You can find this setting in Chrome, Edge and Firefox by hitting F12, go to the Network Tab. Note that in FF, you may have to expand your window pretty wide to find the checkbox.  Its on the far right